# Projective spaces and subspaces. Prove that $\space \mathbb{S_1+S_2}=\mathbb{P}(W_1+W_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-space

Let we have $V$ a vectorial space, $W_1$ and $W_2$ two subspaces of $V$ and $\mathbb{S}_1=\mathbb{P}(W_1)$ and $\mathbb{S}_2=\mathbb{P}(W_2)$ two projective subspaces in the projective space $\mathbb{P}(V)$.

We need to prove that if $\space \mathbb{S_1+S_2} \space $ is the smallest projective subspace that includes $\mathbb{S_1}$ and $\mathbb{S_2}$, is true that $\space \mathbb{S_1+S_2}=\mathbb{P}(W_1+W_2)$.

---

I don't even know how to start with this demonstration... can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you seen the Grassmann formula for projective spaces?

Comment: Not for projective spaces @psidaga

Comment: In my course of geometry we have assumed your proposition as a definition in order to prove the Grassmann formula: Let $\Lambda=\mathbb{P}(U)$ and $\Gamma=\mathbb{P}(V)$ (where $U$ and $V$ are two vector spaces), then $\mathrm{dim}(\Lambda + \Gamma)=\mathrm{dim}(\Lambda)+\mathrm{dim}(\Gamma)-\mathrm{dim}(\Lambda \cap \Gamma)$. If you want I can show you how to prove it using your proposition (that ,as I said first, we have assumed as definition).

Comment: thanks but I'm stuying the grade on mathematics and we need to prove it as an exercise @psidaga

Comment: Maybe could help you to show the double inclusion the fact that :if $U \subseteq V$ vector susbpace of $V$ such that $\mathrm{dim}(U)=r+1$ we can associate the linear subspace  $\Lambda:=\mathbb{P}(U)=\frac {U/\{0\}}{\sim}$, where $\sim$ is the equivalent relation that defines the projective space.